# How do I give only my client access to my API?

Tags: asp.net, rest, security, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing a REST web API that will be used by mobile app clients. I don't want any other client to be able to access the API. Should I just require a password/token that will be used by the mobile apps? Isn't there a way for people to find that password by decompiling my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OWIN OAUTH where a user of the client is required to authenticate and a Bearer authorization token is returned to the client that must be passed in to all secure requests on the WebAPI (a secure request on the WebAPI uses the Authorize attribute)

Take a look at this link http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/#comments

Comment: This looks like a good solution, and that tutorial was helpful. But could a motivated user somehow intercept that bearer token and use it to make his own requests? Does HTTPS stop this?

Comment: @Jutanium That sounds like a great candidate for a separate question! :)

Comment: Ok... also, what about the initial registering of the user? That can't require a bearer token, otherwise the app won't be able to register any user. But if it doesn't have a bearer token, then anyone could spam my api and register users

Comment: That is true but you could deal with registration by sending the user to a web portal to register and therefore not expose register through your API, then you can use "capture" on the register page to protect against injection attacks, of you could implement something on the register API route that protects against that as well

Comment: Capture is the distorted image that requires a physical user to interpret and enter a code to validate that a user is accessing and not 'bot' or script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot create an app with a secret embedded and expect the secret to stay secret.

If you ship the app with the secret (token, user/pass, private key, etc), that information is available in the binary, and someone motivated could extract it.

The normal practice is to install the app, then let the user of the application log in, and store a unique credential for future requests.